# How iOS deleted photos can reappea

Tags: ios, icloud-photo-library

On iOS 11 I had iCloud Photo Library turned on. 
* I deleted a couple hundred photos. 
* I deleted all in the recently deleted photos folder
* I turned off iCloud Photo Library (other devices were still using it, so undeleted photos remained other than on the phone)
* At this point the phone did not contain the deleted photos 
* A week later I turned iCloud Photo Library back on
* A couple days later the photos that had been deleted from the library And then from the deleted photos folder were back

How can this be? I read that a photo deleted from any device using the library deletes it from all devices (in that those photos are no longer in the library) and deleting all in the recently deleted folder should make it permanent.

Comment: It also resurrected the albums that I had deleted once the photos in them were deleted.

Comment: So I notice that when I go into Dropbox on iOS, for example, and tell it to upload from Photos, it sees the albums and photos that existed on my Mac prior to my turning on Cloud Photo Library. As far as Mac Photos is concerned, those albums and photos are no longer there. If I turn off cloud library on the Mac, the Mac lib still exists. once merged when turning it on they would be safe to delete with it off? I.e. Any that are both Mac and cloud would still exist in the cloud when I turn on cloud library again? That sort of makes sense, but not that the phone syncs to the NON cloud library.